# Is there a way or feat to give a weapon the finesse property?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons

Are there rules that describe how to give certain weapons the [finesse property](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/equipment#WeaponProperties)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is nothing in the WoTC published material that allows you to add the finesse property to a weapon.

There are options to use *other* stats than strength for hit or damage if that is your goal. For example from the Hexblade Warlock.

> Whenever you finish a long rest, you can touch one weapon that you are proficient with and that lacks the two-handed property. When you attack with that weapon, you can use your Charisma modifier, instead of Strength or Dexterity, for the attack and damage rolls. - *p.55 Xanathar's Guide to Everything*

Comment: The Sun-Blade enchantment adds finesse and Moonblade can also add finesse. Both, as base items are longswords, but with the Crafting Magical Items rules from Xanathar's your DM may allow applying the template to other weapons.

Answer (score 8):

While there is no way to give a weapon the finesse property, if you merely wish to use Dexterity instead of Strength for attack and damage rolls with a weapon, 3 levels of the Kensei Monk from *Xanathar's Guide to Everything* will do the trick.

Comment: All monks can also use Dexterity instead of Strength for any monk weapons (which only include shortswords and all simple weapons, for non-kensei monks).

Answer (score -5):

Some sources allow for crafting your weapon from Mithril as a means of giving it the finesse property when it otherwise would not have it.  Check with your DM on this.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. Can you support your answer by citing evidence?

Comment: Are the sources you mention for 5th edition? Mithril as a material isn't really a thing, perhaps you a referring to an older edition.

Comment: @linksassin Mithril didn't do that in previous editions anyway, so...yeah.

Comment: @Miniman I hadn't heard of it doing that. However there is so much content for past editions that I don't pretend to know all of it. I didn't want to rule it out as a possibility.